# Will a TCP connection always recover eventually? How quickly?

Tags: windows, tcp

I'm thinking about a simple scheme to transfer data over a very unreliable network: Simply disable all TCP timeouts or set them to extreme values such as a day.

If the network fails temporarily (router unplugged etc.) will the TCP connection recover eventually? How quickly will that happen?

I'm not concerned about transfer speed consistency. Very long pauses are OK.

If this is OS specific then I'd like to know for Windows.

Comment: What kind of scenarios are we considering. If the IP address of the router changes there's no chance of recovering the connection, for example.

Comment: The IP addresses of the two machines would be stable and I can ignore the case that one of the machines disappears.